# error for work iis and visual studio

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation

i install visual studio 2010,but i forgot to install iis before it,so now when i want to run asp.net programs,it gives me this error:
virtual directory not being configured as an application in iis,what should i do now?
i see something in another site that said:
 Right Click on the virtual directory - select properties and then click on "Create" next to the "Application" Label and the textbox. It will automatically create the "application" using the virtual directory's name. Now the application can be accessed. 2. When you have sub-directories in your application, you can have web.config file for the sub-directory. However, there are certain properties which cannot be set in the web.config of the sub-directory such as authentication, session state (you may see that the error message shows the line number where the authentication or sessionstate is declared in the web.config of the sub-directory). The reason is, these settings cannot be overridden at the sub-directory level unless the sub-directory is also configured as an application (as mentioned in the above point). Mostly we have the practice of adding web.config in the sub-directory if we want to protect access to the sub-directory files (say, the directory is admin and we wish to protect the admin pages from unathorized users).

i do this,but it doesn t work

Comment: ok!! but when their answer helped me,i accept them and give them score!!

Comment: Then consider re-framing your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask I for one, have no idea what you are asking above.